# How to override default values of the existing dataflow pipeline options

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'd like to override default values of the existing dataflow pipeline options.
For example, I tried like this

```
public interface MyOptions extends DataflowPipelineOptions {
    // Common options here.
    @Override
    @Default.Class(DataflowPipelineRunner.class)
    Class<? extends PipelineRunner<?>> getRunner();
}

...

MyOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(MyOptions.class);
```

But this doesn't work.
Is there any way to override default values of the existing options?

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, this is not possible in the form you described. You could accomplish something similar like this, by going through an "intermediate" custom argument with your custom default value:

```
public interface MyOptions extends PipelineOptions {
  @Default.Class(DataflowPipelineRunner.class)
  Class<? extends PipelineRunner<?>> getMyRunner();
}

PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation();
options.as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class).setRunner(
    options.as(MyOptions.class).getMyRunner());
```